# Setting tabindex on focus dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, accessibility

here is what my div in the DOM,

```
<span tabindex="0">Help needed???</span>
<h2 tabindex="0">Some text</h2>
```

Now what i see was, the screen reader is reading the exact dom structure. I need the h2 tag to read first and the span to read next.

Changing the structure of dom is leading to multiple javascript issues (I played with more number of prev() codes in my jquery)

I tried changing the tabindex="1" to the h2 tag, but no luck.

Will the screen reader reads only in hierarchical order? I am using JAWS..

Cheers!
Steeve

Answer (score 2):

Correct, 'browsing' with a screen reader does not follow the tabindex order, it follows the DOM.

If you used positive numbers for tabindex, the tab order would start on the first one, and then go back to the DOM structure. It would not match the 'browse' order, which is very confusing.

Have you tried nesting the help text in the heading?

```
<h2>Some text
  <span>Help needed???</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not this

```
<span tabindex="2">Help needed???</span>
<h2 tabindex="1">Some text</h2>
```